# Running SQLCMD from task scheduler messes up character encoding

Tags: cmd, export-to-csv, scheduler, sqlcmd, codepages

I have a view which contains special (Danish/Norwegian) characters. I want to select some rows and export them in a csv file. I created a batch file ***sqlselection.bat*** and contains the following code:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\sqlcmd" -f o:65001 -S myDBserver,1433\myDB -U myUser -P myPassword  -s, -W -Q "Select * from myDB.dbo.myview" > "D:\exportTo\here.csv"
```

Running sqlselection.bat by doubleclicking the .bat file produces the file *here.csv* with the correct codepage. 
However, running the same batch file as a trigger on a **scheduled task**, creates the file *here.csv* without the special characters.

The characters ø,æ,å are replaced with a single quote "'" and it's driving me INSANE! 
By this stage I've hit a dead-end and I am open to any suggestion. Any takers?
[image: single quote replaces special character]

[image: the scheduled task]

Comment: Have you tried putting `CHCP 65001` at the beginning of `sqlselection.bat`?

Comment: THANK YOU! I spent my whole morning trying to decipher this